# ES6 Importing npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I'm getting started with web development and am having trouble importing modules that I've installed using `npm i MODULE -S` into a my `.html` within a `script`. My file structure resembles:

**SETUP:**

```
    project
    |_ node_modules
    |_ public
    |   |_ css
    |   |_ js
    |   |   |_ libs
    |   |   |_ index.mjs
    |   |_ index.html
    |_ server
        |_ server.mjs
```

the `index.html` file is very simple and resembles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JSON and AJAX</title>

    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>JSON and AJAX</h1>
      <button id="btn">Fetch Info for 3 New Objects</button>
    </header>

    <div id="animal-info"></div>

    <script type="module" src="js/index.mjs"></script>

    <div id="msgid"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the `index.mjs` file:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and for completness the `server.mjs` file

```
// const path = require('path');
import path from 'path';

import express from 'express';

const app = express();

const __dirname = path.resolve();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.set('port', port);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**PROBELM**

when I run `node --experimental-modules server/server.mjs` my page loads and I'm able to visit it in `localhost:8080`, but when I open the developer tools in chrome I'm presented with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

**Attempted resolution**

1) I've changed to import statement in the `index.mjs` file to be:

```
import $ from '.jquery';

import $ from './jquery';

'import $ from '../../node_modules/jquery';
```

which output the following message:

```
GET http://localhost:49160/js/jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:49160/js/jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:49160/node_modules/jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

2) I've attempted to copy the the `jquery` folder from the `node_modules` directory into the `libs` directory and rerun so that `index.js` only has the following code:

```
import $ from './libs/jquery';
```

but I get the  following error:

```
GET http://localhost:49160/js/libs/jquery/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**EXTRA**

When I follow the documentation on the [Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) page and develop my own modules everything works fine, but when I try with thrid party modules I am presented with a series of errors.

Comment: HTTP 404 has nothing to do with modules - your file is not available by the path you're trying to load from.

Comment: Seeing you are very new to web development why are you wasting your time learning a legacy library like jQuery? You should be spending your time learning a modern web development framework like Angular, React or Vue. Do not waste your time learning such an outdated method.

Comment: @Adran Brand, the goal is to learn React. I've just picked `jQuery` as an example module thinking it would make the above explanation easier, but I'm unable to import any other thrid party module that I install using `npm install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR;

`import $ from '/js/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js'`

or

`import $ from './libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js'`

There are two different problems in your two attempts.

> `import $ from 'jquery';`

This sort of import by name will not work because your browser doesn't know where to search for jquery. Depending on the browser, if you have a `jquery.js` file in the root (/public) of your server, it *might* work, but no guarantees.

> import $ from '.jquery';
>
> import $ from './jquery';
>
> 'import $ from '../../node_modules/jquery';

These are all, unfortunately, the wrong path. ES6 modules are loaded from the file, not from a directory, and package.json is ignored. So all of these would need `dist/jquery.js` on the end to stand a chance. Also, based on your directory structure, none are correct (assuming jquery dir is in /public/js/libs). The second one is the closes but is missing `./libs` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

NPM type installation

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

TypeScript reference

```
/// <reference types="jquery" />
```

The key is to realize, that jQuery is accessible through global scope
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html#global-libraries

and can be referenced via `reference` keyword instead of `import`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html#dependencies-on-global-libraries

Answer (score -1):

The correct import is

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: the console outputs: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jquery". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` When attempting to add those paths I'm presented with the same error messages as in my original post.

Comment: Installing packages with npm is best suited to a build environment like webpack. I am not sure what your folder structure is but start with a React seed app to get you started. Give up on the jQuery.

Comment: If you want to just play with some jQuery then the link to the CDN you have commented out will work just fine. No need for NPM.

Comment: @AdrianBrand TypeScript will not compile, if it use jQuery, referencing from CDN. Installing types does not help, TypeScript is probably still looking for jQuery.js

Comment: @AdrianBrand sometimes developers don't have the option to move away from jQuery because the client is not willing to pay for the time required to rewrite the site or application in React.