# how to use npm package with hugo

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, hugo, static-site

I have a simple hugo site made with this command

```sh
hugo new site quickstart
```

and inside `layouts/_default/baseof.html` i have included a JavaScript file, named `script.js`
and inside `script.js` i have this code:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
```

but when i check my browser console, it shows me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “jquery”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

in my root folder, where i have all the folders like "content", "data", "public", "archetypes" i have installed `jquery` using npm but i still get this error.

Note: I don't want to include jquery from a cdn, or download the file.

Edit:

I tried using relative path to jquery inside node_modules folder using this code:

```js
import $ from '../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min'
```

but then get this error:

```sh
GET http://localhost:1313/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min
```

Comment: Because your jQuery module is not in the default "node_modules" folder, you need to specify a relative path, as suggested by the error message you receive.

Comment: I've edited the question, with your answer, but it still didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622376/es6-importing-npm-module  
But, using hugo - I would do this via go modules - but that's just me...
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/importing-js-from-node-packages/23545/2, note: I agree with BEP in this discourse thread.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like HUGO is searching `node_modules` in the public folder.
You might want to move the `node_modules` to the `/public` folder and see if it resolves the jQuery not found issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34625557)